# AMD Mobility Radeon FGLRX will not work

Tags: ati

I have a big issue here

I have a AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250 and when  install the fglrx and   i reboot it wont show the whole unity desktop like no launcher and no upper bar,

i have ubuntu 13.04 and its like fresh and brand new and its fully up to date.
please assist me

Answer (score 0):

From what I know,the Radeon HD 4xxx series is no longer supporter by Ubuntu 13.04.

I have HD 4350/4550 and after trying to do the same thing,Ubuntu got messed up,it recognized my display as a laptop and my resolution went from berserk,I couldn't see anything anymore except the middle of the screen...couldn't see the menus,the bars,anything.Had to reinstall in the end...so it might be something similar.